# using wpf from powershell

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, binding

I’ve started playing around with powershell.
At the moment I’m trying to load a C# class which displays a WPF window, so for so good.
A TextBlock placed in the window binds to a Property in the class. (I’ve tested the binding in a CmdLine Application and it works fine)… but when I load the class from powershell using add-tape the binding won’t work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$a =@"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _showed = false;
        private String _myString;

        public String MyString
        {
            get { return _myString; }
            set
            {
                _myString = value;
                if (!_showed)
                    ThreadStuff();
                OnPropertyChanged("MyString");
            }
        }

        public TestClass()
        {
        }

        public TestClass(String value)
        {
            _myString = value;
        }

        private void ThreadStuff()
        {
            _showed = true;
            var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                CreateWindow();
                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            }))
            {
                IsBackground = true
            };
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void CreateWindow()
        {
            var w = new Window();
            var g = new Grid();
            g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

            for (int i = 0; i < g.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < g.ColumnDefinitions.Count; j++)
                {
                    var b = new Button { Content = new TextBlock { Text = i.ToString() } };
                    Grid.SetRow(b, i);
                    Grid.SetColumn(b, j);
                    g.Children.Add(b);
                }
            }

            var t = new TextBlock();
            var binding = new Binding { Source = MyString, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
            t.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);

            (g.Children[g.Children.Count - 1] as Button).Content = t;

            w.Content = g;
            w.Show();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $a -ReferencedAssemblies presentationcore, presentationframework, windowsbase, "System.Xaml"

$test = New-Object TestClass
$test.MyString = 'hi from powershell'
```

Btw.
I’m working with powershell for the first time (I’ve just worked with C# until now ).
In the end it is my goal to load a Xaml file as view and a C# file as view mode, put them together and set the property of the vm from powershell  (Yes it is totally stupide and it would be much easier  to write a normal WPF application… but I’ve to do it this way…school now a days^^ )

Answer (score 1):

What version of powershell are you using?  Your code "works" for me in Powershell 3.0 on Win8.

I say "works" because it works the same as when I run it via a C# console application:

- Nothing happens until you set `MyString`
- First time you set `MyString`, a GUI pops up, and lower right quadrant contains the value of `MyString`
- Nothing happens on subsequent modifications of `MyString` (The binding is not set up correctly, so the text won't update when you update `MyString`)

If this is your desired behavior, and it's not working AT ALL, then it might be an issue with older versions of PS.

I suspect your real issue is that the binding isn't working.  That's because this line:

```
var binding = new Binding { Source = MyString, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
```

should be

```
var binding = new Binding { Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay, Path = new PropertyPath("MyString") };
```

Making that change, everything seems hooked up just fine in both C# console app and powershell.

Comment: Thanks, now it works for the first time setting MyString (The text gets displayed in on the UI).
But the label TextBlock doesn’t change when I set the value again…

After this commands:
 PS  >$test.MyString = 'hi from powershell'
 PS > $test.MyString = 'new string'
 PS > $test.MyString
 new string
 PS >

The UI still displays “hi from powershell”.

Btw.
I’ve powershell 3.0

Comment: I verified it works before posting.  What you are seeing is what I saw with your original code.  Are you sure the type was successfully updated, using the updated code?  Try opening a new powershell window to get a clean session.

Comment: I’ve killed all the powershell processes and started a new one… now it works.
**Thank you very much!**